# Can we suppress or change the initial descriptive comments with tikzDevice?

Tags: r, rscript, tikzdevice

Consider the following R-code:

```
## Uncomment the following line if tikzDevice is absent
## install.packages('tikzDevice')
library(tikzDevice)
tikz('test.tex')
dev.off()
```

This produces a `test.tex` in the working directory with the following content:

```latex
% Created by tikzDevice version 0.12.3.1 on 2022-11-12 18:17:25
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

I want to either suppress these comments or change their comment character. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm afraid `tikz` requires a file in disk, and unless there is an explicit option unknown for me, your only way is to delete these lines manually after closing device : `writeLines(readLines("test.tex")[-1:-2], "test.text")`

Comment: First line can be suppresed with the arg `timestamp == F`